# Letter for Grade for multiple students

Tags: python, list, project

```
def getGradeInfo():
    numStudent = int(input('Total number of students: '))
    getGrades = input(f'Enter {numStudent} scores: ')
    gradeListNum = getGrades.split(' ')
    maxScore = int(max(gradeListNum[0:numStudent]))
    gradeListLetter = []
    
    for grade in gradeListLetter:
        if int(grade) >= maxScore - 10:
            gradeListLetter.append('A')
        elif int(grade) >= maxScore - 20:
            gradeListLetter.append('B')
        elif int(grade) >= maxScore - 30:
            gradeListLetter.append('C')
        elif int(grade) >= maxScore - 40:
            gradeListLetter.append('D')
        else:
            gradeListLetter.append('F')
    a = 1
    while a<= numStudent:
        print(f'Student{a} score is {gradeListNum[a-1]} and grade is')
        a+=1
getGradeInfo()
```

I can get the input for the number of students in the code but can't figure out how to assign the letter to each of the student's grades for the print statement

Comment: `for grade in gradeListLetter` won't do anything in the code you've shown because `gradeListLetter` is an empty list. Did you mean to iterate over `gradeListNum`?

Comment: Note that a good Stack Overflow question focuses on the technical problem that prevented you from reaching your goal yourself; not on what that goal was. The next person to get stuck in the same place probably will be doing something that isn't related to letter grades, but if the question is written to be about letter grades, how will they find and learn from it?

Answer (score 3):

As `Adam Oppenheimer` said,

```
for grade in gradeListLetter:
```

should be

```
for grade in gradeListNum:
```

---

Also,

```
print(f'Student{a} score is {gradeListNum[a-1]} and grade is')
```

should be

```
print(f'Student {a}: score is {gradeListNum[a - 1]} and grade is {gradeListLetter[a - 1]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `gradeListLetter` which is empty, try iterating over `gradeListNum` instead.

You also aren't printing the letter grade in your print statement.